# Variable product dropdowns does not appear in the custom product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an e-commerce shop using WordPress that uses Woocommerce. I have a custom page for products page that needs to hold the dropdowns menus (from the variation attribute). But the drop down does not appear. How can call those variations into this page.

This is my code for the single-product.php:

```
<?php
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
?>
<div class="ProductViewing_DescSizing">
    <div class="row">
     <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
        <?php $terms = get_the_terms($product->id, $attribute_name); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label><!-- get attribute name per product -->
                <select class="form-control">
                 <?php foreach ($terms as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"> <?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <div class="addtocart">
        <a href="<?php echo "cart/?add-to-cart=47&variation_id=88&quantity=3&attribute_pa_colour=blue&attribute_pa_size=m"; ?>"><input type="submit" name="" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn btn-red btn-addtocart"></a>
    </div>


    <a href="" class="showguide">SHOW Size guide</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the values of the variables you are using?

Comment: Yes. I already entered the price. Does it have a short code to call the dropdown variations in the custom product page (and not in the shop of the Woocommerce) ? I already research about it and the tutorials shows that it SHOULD show automatically in the page.

Comment: I actually meant the `$attributes` and `$terms` you are using, do they contain the information you expect them to hold? Did you check that?

Comment: Yes. This actually shows these dropdowns.

[link](http://prnt.sc/ecmbnr) 

But it not "auto generated and Add To Cart shows even if choosing from the dropdowns is not yet complete.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is working and what is not. Maybe this code helps http://www.remicorson.com/display-woocommerce-product-variations-dropdown-on-the-shop-page/